# Kubernetes: NodePort Service not load balance to pods on others nodes

Tags: kubernetes

**Environment:**

- 1 master, 3 worker
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04, provisioned by Vagrant with 3 network interfaces (NAT, hostonly, bridge)
- Kubernetes: 1.21
- Docker: 20.10.5
- Pod Network: Weave Net

**Problems:**
NodePort Service did not load balance to pods on others Node. For example:

- Worker1: pod1, pod2
- Worker2: pod3, pod4
- Worker3: Have no pods

When I issued curl command to :

- http://worker1:30001: I could reach service on pod1, pod2 only
- http://worker2:30001: I could reach service on pod3, pod4 only
- http://worker3:30001: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 30001: No route to host

Additional information:

```sh
k get nodes -o wide
```

```sh
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION       CONTAINER-RUNTIME
vm-150   Ready    control-plane,master   35m   v1.21.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   4.15.0-128-generic   docker://20.10.5
vm-163   Ready    <none>                 31m   v1.21.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   4.15.0-128-generic   docker://20.10.5
vm-216   Ready    <none>                 31m   v1.21.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   4.15.0-128-generic   docker://20.10.5
vm-217   Ready    <none>                 28m   v1.21.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   4.15.0-128-generic   docker://20.10.5
```

```sh
k get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
```

```sh
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-4sstw    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.4   vm-216   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-69jdv    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.7   vm-163   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-9cshc    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.6   vm-216   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-bhsqr    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.6   vm-163   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-dwlfv    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.5   vm-216   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-kfwm7    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.3   vm-163   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-mxtrq    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.4   vm-163   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-qr458    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.5   vm-163   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-rg594    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.7   vm-216   <none>           <none>
default       hello-deploy-6575485494-vt6d8    1/1     Running   0          33m   10.32.0.3   vm-216   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-558bd4d5db-bbxl7         1/1     Running   0          37m   10.32.0.2   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-558bd4d5db-kphk5         1/1     Running   0          37m   10.32.0.3   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-vm-150                      1/1     Running   0          37m   10.0.2.15   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-vm-150            1/1     Running   0          37m   10.0.2.15   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-vm-150   1/1     Running   0          37m   10.0.2.15   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-2j2f8                 1/1     Running   0          31m   10.0.2.15   vm-217   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-pbvvd                 1/1     Running   0          34m   10.0.2.15   vm-163   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-pwx7p                 1/1     Running   0          34m   10.0.2.15   vm-216   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-x9d8z                 1/1     Running   0          37m   10.0.2.15   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-vm-150            1/1     Running   0          37m   10.0.2.15   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   weave-net-jnkjp                  2/2     Running   1          31m   10.0.2.15   vm-217   <none>           <none>
kube-system   weave-net-l8fmm                  2/2     Running   0          34m   10.0.2.15   vm-163   <none>           <none>
kube-system   weave-net-lgzqp                  2/2     Running   0          37m   10.0.2.15   vm-150   <none>           <none>
kube-system   weave-net-mwvzj                  2/2     Running   0          34m   10.0.2.15   vm-216   <none>           <none>
```

**Deployment manifest:**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deploy

spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-pod
        image: ngocchien/chien_test:1.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-svc
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30001
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-world
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have a replicas of 1 in your Deployment; that doesn't seem to match up with the output you have posted. Can you please Describe the Service object?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Is weave even working? If NodePorts can't send you from one node to another, sounds like something is wrong with your SDN. Maybe check for weave pods logs? The error mentions failing to connect to `localhost`?